# SQL Server Group Results into Period Relative to Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I'm looking to groups average scores from a query into each day of date. I'm aware that you can get the week of day etc. part of a date with something like:

```
'Week ' + CAST(DATEPART(wk, s.date_taken) AS (varchar(2)) Week
```

This is not what I am after though. I filter my results during a join to get the four weeks prior to and four weeks after a specific date like so:

```
INNER JOIN
    swa_speeding AS s
    ON i.policy_id = s.policy_id
    AND s.date_taken BETWEEN DATEADD(WEEK,-4,i.note_date) AND DATEADD(WEEK,4,i.note_date)
```

The issue is that there is a lot of data being joined from the table `swa_speeding` and `i.note_date` changes on each record.

In effect what I am asking for help on doing is grouping all the results into the day that the average came from relative to `i.note_date` with `i.note_date` being the mid point within the results.The results should look like:

[image: Example]

Here's my query so far:

```
;SELECT
    datepart(day, s.date_taken) [Day],
    AVG(s.dlyspeed)

FROM
    swa_intervention AS i

INNER JOIN
    swa_speeding AS s
    ON i.policy_id = s.policy_id
    AND s.date_taken BETWEEN DATEADD(WEEK,-4,i.note_date) AND DATEADD(WEEK,4,i.note_date)

INNER JOIN
    swa_policy AS p
    ON i.policy_id = p.id

WHERE
    i.id = 431

GROUP BY
    datepart(day, s.date_taken)
```

Hope this makes sense what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new field to group on, as below.

```
SELECT
    [GroupName],
    AVG(s.dlyspeed)

FROM
    swa_intervention AS i

INNER JOIN
    swa_speeding AS s
    ON i.policy_id = s.policy_id
    AND s.date_taken BETWEEN DATEADD(WEEK,-4,i.note_date) AND DATEADD(WEEK,4,i.note_date)

INNER JOIN
    swa_policy AS p
    ON i.policy_id = p.id

CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN s.date_taken > i.note_date THEN 'After' 
                    WHEN s.date_taken = i.note_date THEN 'On'
                    WHEN s.date_taken < i.note_date THEN 'Before'
            END [GroupName]
) a

WHERE               
    i.id = 431

GROUP BY
    [GroupName]
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, it doesn't however like the `CASE` statement within the `Cross Apply`. Any ideas please?

Comment: Nevermind, sorry figured out it was missing a `SELECT`! Thanks for your help!